# Devise Custom Registration final step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting the following error when trying to customize my devise user registration flow.

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm trying to implement devise registration with 2 different user types.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :players, where(:user_type => 'player')
  ...
end
```

and on the vanilla devise registration a user selects their `user_type` for what type of user they are signing up as:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :user_type, 'Register As' %>
    <%= f.select :user_type, [['Player', 'player'], ['Coach', 'coach']] %>
  </div>
  ....
<% end %>
```

I want to implement an experience where the user clicks a link to signup as either user type, then that user_type is passed into that form depending on which link (user_type) was clicked.

So, I have a custom registrations controller to achieve this in `controllers/users`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  

  def players
  end

  def coaches
  end
end
```

and in my routes

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"},
    skip: [:sessions] do
      get '/signup_player' => "users/registrations#players", :as => :new_player_registration
      get '/signup_coach' => "users/registrations#coaches", :as => :new_coach_registration
    end
```

And the device def in application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
     :user
   end

   def resource
     @resource ||= User.new
   end

   def devise_mapping
     @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
   end
end
```

Finally, I'm rendering the vanilla devise registration form in `/views/registrations/players.html.erb` (obv I expect to set the user_type to player on this view).

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%=  devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :user_type, 'Register As' %>
    <%= f.select :user_type, [['Player', 'player'], ['Coach', 'coach']] %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_club %>
    <%= f.text_field :current_club %>
  </div>

  ...

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

on this view I am getting the following error.

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

I fundamentally understand the error but I don't understand why or how.

## UPDATE potential solution

Change form_for params to read-

```
<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user, :url => registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

and in users/registrations_controller.rb

```
  def players
    @user = User.new
  end
  def coaches
    @user = User.new
  end
```

Comment: After digging deeper into the devise src https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/b8ed2f31608eccb6df6d5bb2e66238d6dfc4bcfc/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb , it seems that form_for isn't recongnizing the params as user objects. But, I thought that was the point of the modifications to the application helper.

Comment: So based on my understanding of the error I have made the following changes in the update to the original posting. Would be really excellent if someone is able to comment on this approach. Taking a "make it work and then make it work better approach"